# Facebook Comments: Different comments on different pages

Tags: comments, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

I have a static site. Facebook comment "thanks" on page1.php is also visible at all pages i.e. page2.php, page3.php etc. I have FB application API.
How can I set the comment "thanks" for page1.php only not for the all pages? I am not much technical, referring to a tutorial will be highly appreciated.
Thanks & regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/, the url you use gets programmed into the plugin code you copy onto your site.  You will need to hand modify the data-href for each page you paste it into.

This would go on page 1

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com/page1.php" data-num-posts="2" data-width="500"></div>
```

This would go on page 2

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com/page2.php" data-num-posts="2" data-width="500"></div>
```

etc...

Comment: It seems I have to change page names in tag and put this tag into every single page to get comments on appropriate page. Not like the dynamic pages (like Wordpress and Joomla, install plugin and it will sort out where comment was actually submitted).

Comment: Yes, that's how you will need to code it.  Each php page will get their own unique href.

Comment: Alright! Thank you very much for your time and comprehensive information regarding to my query.

Comment: Be sure to mark this answer correct if it resolved your situation. :)  Thanks.